# Reading enum values dynamically in angular template

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

I am working on an angular app. I have a enum as follows

```
export class myEnum {
  "status1" = 1,
  "status2"  = 2,
  "status3"  = 3,
  "status4" = 4,
  "status5" = 5
 }
```

In my html I have a data coming from api and I am using *ngFor to display it as follows:

```
<div>*ngFor="let mydata of data"</div>
```

Now this data will have a status field in integer(can access using {{mydata.status}}) which will match above mentioned enum. In my html I want to pass/match this number and display it as string. Suppose from API if status coming as 4, then I want to have a code in which I pass this value and it should match it in enum and display "status4" on screen. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are using incorrect syntax for *ngFor loop.

Your Template code will be -

```
<div *ngFor="let mydata of data">
  {{status[mydata]}}
</div>
```

and in the .ts file, you can use a const object as a lookup object, so that you can directly access the value by key. In Enums you cannot have a numeric key, so using an object can be an easy and effective choice here.

You can write it as -

```
const statusLookup = {
    1:'status1',
    2:'status2',
    3:'status3',
    4:'status4',
    5:'status5'
  }
```

If you still want to use enums for any other specific reason, you can use a custom pipe (to get the key by value from enum) and plug it in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Your component must look something like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export enum StatusEnum{
   offline = 1,
   online = 2
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})


export class AppComponent  {

  public statusEnum = StatusEnum;
  
  public data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      status: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      status: 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Then in your view you do something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data">
  <p>{{statusEnum[d.status]}}</p>
</div>
```

Check this out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-enum-in-template

ps: I named the Enum StatusEnum just for clarity!